# JQuery Wildcard ID Selector With Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a jquery selector to select all elements with an ID starting with `newInstruction`, with a class of `.individualInstruction`.

This should match divs with id `newInstruction0`, `newInstruction1`, etc.

I can do this separately like this:

```
$('[id^="newInstruction"]')
```

and

```
$('.individualInstruction')
```

However, I'm getting syntax errors when I try to combine them. This is probably simple, but is there a jquery guru out there than can point out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine them with no space like

```
$('[id^="newInstruction"].individualInstruction')
```

```js
document.write($('[id^="newInstruction"].individualInstruction').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="newInstruction1" class="individualInstruction"></div>
<div id="newInstruction2" class="individualInstruction"></div>
<div id="newInstruction3" class="individualInstruction"></div>
```

Comment: That caused a syntax error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: id^="newInstruction"].individualInstruction

Comment: @Jason, see the snippet example

Comment: Whoops, when I readded that to the code, I left off the starting bracket, causing the syntax error. Your code worked fine, thanks. I'll accept the answer as soon as the system lets me.